# Trouble Parsing JSON object in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am having trouble in parsing the JSON object, not sure where I am wrong?

Here is HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="user in _users" ng-init="myInfo=parJson(user.response)">{{myInfo.docs[0].FIRST_NAME}}</div>
    </div>
```

Here is Angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.getName = function(user) {
    return "Names";
  };

  $scope._users = [{
    "responseHeader": {
      "status":0,
        "QTime":1,
    },"response":{
    "docs":[{
            "FIRST_NAME":"John",
            "LAST_NAME" : "Smith"}]             
    }
  }];
  $scope.parJson = function(json) {
      return JSON.parse(json);
    }
}
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code i can see that "user.response" is already a JSON object, you don't need to parse it again. One thing you can do if you are not sure if your response is a JSON object or JSON string you can add a check in you "parJson" function

```
$scope.parJson = function(json) {
 if(typeof json != "object")
  return JSON.parse(json);
 else
  return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra comma after QTime property. Remove it and try again. Use [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json.